# Unable to open the Excel file attached to work item in Azure Devops

Tags: c#, rest, api, azure-devops

I am creating a tool for attaching the excel files to work items using Azure Devops REST API.I am able to add the excel file to work item but when I was trying to open that it just says "file foramt or file extension not valid". I appreciate any suggestions or any inputs.

Edited:
As per the sugesstion of Lance-Li , i converted the excel file to bytes and send that in request body like below

```
 byte[] filedata = File.ReadAllBytes(filepath);
dynamic WorkItem = new List<dynamic>() {

                new
                {

                  filedata,
                }

            };
    var WorkItemValue = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(WorkItem),Encoding.UTF8, "application/json-patch+json");
```

now sending above workitem value to post method with content-type=application\octet-stream. but still i am facing format issue.did I make any mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally we call [Attachments-Create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/attachments/create?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1#upload-a-binary-file)(Upload the attachment to the attachment store) and then [Add an attachment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20items/update?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1#add-an-attachment)(Add the attachment from attachment store to the work item) to add local attachment to workitem.

**Cause of the issue:**

We should be careful when we upload the attachment using first rest api(Attachments - Create). In the post request, the `filename=xxx` doesn't receive any path to the file. It **won't** fetch the file from desktop or other folders.

After several tests, I reproduced the same issue like yours. Also I find that if we run the post request, it actually just **created** one **new** file with same name instead of fetching local file. For example, if I have a local `test.txt` file with content `just for test`, in my request body I have `"User text content to upload"`, the result is to get one attachment named `test.txt` with content `"User text content to upload"`.

So I think you may upload a `xx.xlsx` file with text content. That's why we got `file foramt not valid` error.

Two workarounds:

1.Upload it as [binary file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/attachments/create?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1#upload-a-binary-file), convert the excel file to binary file and paste the binary content to the request body. (About is it possible to convert excel and how to do that, that's another issue so I don't talk about it here)

2.Another workaround I finally found is using `-Infile` in `Invoke-RestMethod` command and it works well!

(If you're using something like `postman` to run the api, contenttype=>`application/octet-stream`, body=>`binary`)

My Powershell script about `Attachments-Create`:

```
$token = "YourPat"

$url="https://dev.azure.com/YourOrgName/_apis/wit/attachments?fileName=YourFileName.xlsx&api-version=5.1"

$token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($token)"))

$filepath="YourFilePath\YourFileName.xlsx"

$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} -Method Post -InFile $filepath -ContentType application/octet-stream

Write-Host $response
```

Hope all above helps :) And since the cause of the original issue is only about the usage of first api, so I won't talk about the second one here...

**In addition:** If someone is using C# client api to upload the binary file, try using contenttype `application\json`, info from **dhulipala murali**. And if someone is using PS/postman, `application/octet-stream` works well at my side.

Comment: Thanks @Lance Li-MSFT, i tried to send the file as a binary but still issue persists. i added my code above in question. can you correct me?

Comment: And to upload one local file successfully, we need to use two apis, the first one's contenttype is `application/octet-stream` while second one is application/json-patch+json.

Comment: Thanks very much@Lance Li-MSFT, your idea did a trick for me. Now i am able to upload and opening without any format issues. But one small correction, we have to upload the binary file using "application\json" only.when i use application\octet-stream got an error.

Comment: @dhulipalamurali Good hint! I'll update the answer with this useful info :)