# Power Automate - Azure Devops - Create Work Item With Attachments

Tags: azure-devops, power-automate, azure-boards

I am currently establishing integration between Azure DevOps boards and Power automate. I have created a simple flow with two features

- It creates a new issue-type when an email is received
- I can establish a parent-child relationship. It means a link to a parent

Now I want to try another customization. I want to attach email attachments to my newly created work item. I went through the documentation. It states, currently this feature is not available.
Is there any other alternate way to achieve this?

Thanks,
Bee

Answer (score 2):

To attach attachment to work item has't been supported yet, but it has been raised as a feature request [here](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Power-Automate-Ideas/Allow-attachments-to-be-included-when-creating-Azure-DevOps-work/idc-p/259660#M5669).

> Is there any other alternate way to achieve this?

Here're two possible directions I found:

1.Save the attachment to one-drive/sharepoint and then pass the file link to Workitem's description field. (Create/update the work item)

[image]

Hint from [paddlesnap's reply in this post](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Power-Automate-Ideas/Allow-attachments-to-be-included-when-creating-Azure-DevOps-work/idc-p/259660#M5669).

Ps: They aren't true attachments in the work item, but they are at least accessible.

2.Implement an Azure Function that using the DevOps API will upload the attachment and then attach them to the specified DevOps Work Item.

Hint from [hammer's replies in this similar ticket](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/Create-work-item-at-Azure-DevOps-from-an-email-with-attachments/m-p/253332/highlight/true#M25293).

Actually I think we can also use [HTTP action](https://flow.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/http-card-tutorial/) **twice** to call azure devops rest api for [Upload attachment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/attachments/create?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1#upload-a-binary-file) and [Link the attachment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20items/update?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1#add-an-attachment), similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60702452/10910450). However I'm stuck at how to convert the http request in PostMan into Http action in Power Automate...(I'm familiar with Azure Devops and PostMan, however I'm not familiar with Power Automate)

Comment: i will look into your reply in more detail. i have not used AZURE devops API before. Which solution you think is more cleaner?

Comment: @benz 1.Direction1 is the easiest way. (But I'm not sure if you like this kind of workaround, since it just save the link to Description instead of attaching attachment) 2.Direction2 from hammer looks like complex, but at least two members have stated that it can work to attach the attachment. It meets your expected behavior however it's [not free](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/functions/). 3.Direction3... Hmm, I'm sure it can work in PostMan or Powershell in local machine, but I'm not sure how to convert those steps into Http action in Power Automate :-(

Comment: i will get back very soon, once i have tried solution - 1

Comment: Sure, feel free to let me know if there's any update~

Comment: i am trying solution today and will keep you posted, how it goes.