# Upload attachments to Azure devops

Tags: azure-devops

I am trying to get an attachemnt using GET https://dev.azure.com/org/_apis/wit/attachments/9532fc2b?api-version=5.1 using c# using http client.
I am getting the response something like this "PK\u0003\u...".

After getting this response i want to upload it back to another organisation in ADO.
I don't want to download it.Using the GET and POST I need to do this. When I am doing POST using httpclient, it says successfull and created. But if click on the url a file with avague name is downloaded and I am not able to open it.

Answer (score 1):

To upload attachment, we need to [upload attachment to attachment store](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/attachments/create?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1#upload-a-binary-file) first and then [attach the attachment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20items/update?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1#add-an-attachment) to specific work item. (I think you may lack the first step)

And the file to be uploaded should be binary file, see similar ticket [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60692208/unable-to-open-the-excel-file-attached-to-work-item-in-azure-devops/60702452#60702452).